# Request mapping placeholder with slash

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I would like to realize the following:

```
@RequestMapping( "/archive/{date}.html" ) // e.g. /archive/2012/08.html
public String listByDate( @PathVariable( "date" ) @DateTimeFormat( iso = ISO.DATE, pattern = "yyyy/MM" ) Calendar cal, ... )
```

But I'm just getting a 404.

I guess this is because I'm trying to use a slash in between the `{date}` placeholder?

What do I need to do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not split `{date}` into `{year}/{month}`?

```
@RequestMapping( "/archive/{year}/{month}.html" )
public String listByDate( @PathVariable( "year" )...
```

Comment: Because then I would need two `@DateTimeFormat` or need to do the validation check by hand

Comment: @dtrunk I don't see much problems with it. You can use standard library to check date.

Comment: Work/Code that isn't needed... It would avoid understanding this as well.

Answer (score 3):

To include a "/" in a URL parameter it would need to be URL-encoded (otherwise it looks like a path element).

Your request should work if it looks like this:

```
/archive/2012%2F08.html
```

Comment: thanks for that information. that helped me to understand my issue. i guess it isn't possible to do this in one step and i need to split it in two variables like @Ivan said?!

Comment: If the client calling your service expects it to look like a path then yes, you're better off capturing it as two parameters